# How do i check my twitter application on localhost?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I want to check an example of posting a tweet from a form so I created an app. But for testing on my local server when I'm registering the app and entering the CALLBACK URL as http://localhost/mytwitterexample its not taking it as a valid URL.

How do I remove this ambiguity? I am also looking for some more examples on using twiiter apis, so if you have any blogs or websites to follow let me know.

Comment: Because localhost is YOUR localhost and nobody else in the world can access your site with that url.

Comment: So does it means that there is no way to test that app code locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a placeholder callback URL on your application record on dev.twitter.com -- point it at your personal website or otherwise.

When actually performing the OAuth sequence, always explicitly declare your oauth_callback URL on the request token step. While your official application record can't have your callback labeled as localhost, you can use any kind of valid URI scheme you like when providing the callback, including pointing it at localhost.